# iOS/Android Going back to OpenGL 1.1 instead of using 2.0

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So this question has been asked a few times but the examples I have seen where in 2010,2011

2 years ago I wrote a nice little OpenGL 1.1 3D framework for iOS and I got to understand most of what I wrote :) (did not use GLKit)

This year I thought I would try and write a OpenGl 2.0 version for Android and iOS (GLKIT).  Simple 3D movement, cubes, object picking, collision.  Aim, to build a simple 3D city on both platforms.

OpenGL 2.0 seems like bloody hard work, lighting, shaders etc.  I got the basic movement down and make objects but god I dont know how half of it works.

My question is, in 2013, should I keep at OpenGL 2.0 as no one uses 1.x. Or cut my losses and go back to 1.x which I understood?

I dont need any advance effects that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the time to move to 2.0. It's not just the "effects" that are the benefit of 2.0.

You will get so much more out of it than you are currently getting with 1.1. The performance enhancements from shaders alone is worth the jump. Also, consider that the hardware is moving towards 2.0 as well.

In addition, you'll reap the rewards from having a better understanding of lighting, materials, texture mapping, normals, etc.

So, in short, make the jump. It's worth the time and effort.

Comment: Do you personally do android or iOS?

Comment: Would you recommend any tutorials? Currently stuck on glowing balls and sphere which I have posted about.  I guess sphere should be a loaded object I

Comment: This is the problem with a lot of the tutorials and books out there. There are the ones for absolute beginners, which you're obviously beyond. And there's the ones for advanced, which are straight from nVidia and the like. What's going to help immensely is a book that covers 3d math and graphics like: 3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development by Fletcher Dunn. That will pave the way for being able to follow example code and the advanced tutorials.